# can't compile Xamarin.forms basic program

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Im running basic features on visual studio on mac os and i get the following exception: 
"system.invalidcastexception specified cast is not valid"

the class is "page.xaml.g.cs which i didn't edit..

I have only 2 pages in the program.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you rename it to something other than `Page`

Comment: Im new to Xamarin, what do you mean by "rename" it? its actually "mainPage" if this is helpful..

Comment: page.xaml.g.cs is the autogenerate file of page.xaml, which is conflicting with the Xamarin's inbuilt Page class, that's the reason I suggested deleting and adding with a different name